# Can i create a PHP PDO project in my vue-project?

Tags: pdo, vue.js, webpack-2

I want to create a pdo project inside a vue-js simple-webpack template is it possible ? my back end is php(PDO) and my front end is vue

Comment: What you asked does not make much sense :-S

Comment: @zerkms what i mean is that Is it possible to create a php pdo files inside a vue simple-webpack template that i just pulled off using npm?

Comment: @zerkms so that my back end is Php(PDO) and my front end is a vue.

Comment: It is possible to create files.